# Algorithm to print the reversed number given by user?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've written a small program in C++ that prompts the user for input, the user gives a number, then the computer displays the number reversed.

For example: 17 becomes 71. 123 becomes 321.

This is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  //for later use.
using namespace std;

int rev(int x)
{
    int r = 0;
    while(x)
    {
        r = (r*10) + (x%10);
        x = x/10;
    }
    return r;
}

int main()
{
    int nr;
    cout << "Give a number: ";
    cin >> nr;
    rev(nr);
    cout << nr; 
    return 0;
}
```

The final result of the program: prints the same number, function has no effect. What am I doing wrong? I tried several solutions but to no avail.

Comment: You are not uptading nr with the returning value of the function.

Comment: Lots of wrong answers for such a straightforward question....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change `rev(nr);` to `nr = rev(nr);`

or alternately change your function to:

```
void rev(int& x)
{
    int r = 0;
    while(x)
    {
        r = (r*10) + (x%10);
        x = x/10;
    }
    x = r;
}
```

Comment: That's good but you need to make rev return void in this case.

Comment: The first solution is better.  I wouldn't advise using the second solution unless you had some reason for it.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it right, but you're not grabbing your return value (the reversed value).

To solve this, just assign or print the return value:

```
cout << rev(nr);
```

or

```
nr = rev(nr);
cout << nr;
```

Comment: This is also a valid answer, besides mydogisbox's answer this also works.

Answer (score 2):

While probably not in the intended spirit, the simple answer is that if you're only going to display it in reverse, you can cheat and just work with a string:

```
std::string input;

std::cin >> input;

std::cout << std::string(input.rbegin(), input.rend());
```

Comment: Or use `std::reverse` directly on the string.  (I've never found a use for this function in production code, but since it's there:-).)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yup, that should work too. I can't say I've ever used it in real code either -- probably at least part of why I didn't think of it.

Comment: Originally this code was meant for C, which has no strings but I wrote it in C++, thanks for this though.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using the value that `rev` returns.  You're just using the value `nr` which you pass to rev, and since you don't pass by reference, rev isn't being affected locally.

What you want to say is:

```
int nr;
cout << "Give a number: ";
cin >> nr;
int result = rev(nr);
cout << result; 
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `std::reverse` function in the STL, which works with collections.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

  long int i = 0;
  do {
    std::cout << "Gimme a number: " << std::endl;
  } while (not (std::cin >> i)); // make sure it *is* a number

  std::string display = std::to_string(i); // C++11

  std::reverse(display.begin(), display.end());

  std::cout << display << "\n";
}
```